# Jquery changing class depending on database value

Tags: jquery

Is it possible, only using jquery, to change a specific css ID depending on which value is on a Postgres database table using jquery .prop()? If so, how is it possible?

For example: if table.column returns value 1, then show the first picture. Else if returns value 2, shows the second picture.

The images' css is as follows, the jquery should bring the corresponding picture according to database value.

```
  #pyramid-step-1 { background-image: url('prm1.png');
    width: 141px;
    height: 117px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-top: -35px;}
  #pyramid-step-2 { background-image: url('prm2.png');
    width: 151px;
    height: 155px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left:-38px;} 
  #pyramid-step-3 { background-image: url('prm3.png');
    width: 151px;
    height: 155px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 6px;}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your answer is __Yes, It is possible.__ You have not asked how? also show your effor

Comment: Thanks Satpal, edited my question with more details.

Comment: use an ajax, get the value, and attach id by `$(this).attr('id', '#pyramid-step-' + returnedId);` But i suggest you to use classes instead of id.

Comment: @lolka_bolka, thank you! So is necessary to use AJAX first to retrieve database value then use jquery to apply its correct class (changed from id to class, thanks!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manage it by conditions like

```
// $foo = 1; your db value

if($foo == 1){
  $("#yourid").removeClass("Your1classname");
  $("#yourid").addClass("Your2classname");
}else{
  $("#yourid").removeClass("Your2classname");
  $("#yourid").addClass("Your1classname");
}
```

and also you may manage images by defining it in the class